# scipy.stats cdf greater than 1

Tags: python, scipy, probability

I'm using scipy.stats and I need the CDF up to a given value x for some distributions, I know PDFs can be greater than 1 because they are not probabilities but densities so they should integrate to 1 even if specific values are greater, but CDFs should never be greater than 1 and when running the cdf function on scipy.stats sometimes I get values like 2.89, i'm completely sure i'm using cdf and not pdf(that was my first guess), this is messing my results and algorithm because I need accumulated probabilities, why is scipy.stats cdf returning values greater than 1 and/or how should I proceed to fix it?

Code for reproducing the issue with a sample distribution and parameters(but it happens with others too):

```
from scipy import stats
distribution = stats.gausshyper
params = [9.482986347673158, 16.65813644507513, -38.11083665959626, 16.08698932118982, -13.387170754433273, 18.352117022674125]
test_val = [-0.512720,1,1]

arg = params[:-2]
loc = params[-2]
scale = params[-1]

print("cdf:",distribution.cdf(test_val,*arg, loc=loc,scale=scale))
print("pdf:",distribution.pdf(test_val,*arg, loc=loc,scale=scale))
```

cdf: [2.68047481 7.2027761  7.2027761 ]
pdf: [2.76857133 2.23996739 2.23996739]

Comment: Which distribution, what parameters? Please add a reproducer

Comment: If it's a bug in scipy, it's probably more appropriate to take it up on the bug tracker for the scipy project. I don't know where that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the parameters that you have specified for the Gaussian hypergeometric (HG) distribution, specifically in the third element of `params`, which is the parameter beta in the HG distribution (see equation 2 in [this paper](http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/ince/v7n14/v7n14a02.pdf) for the definiton of the density of the Gauss Hypergeometric distr.). This parameter **has to be positive** for HG to have a valid density. Otherwise, the density won't integrate to 1, which is exactly what is happening in your example. With a negative beta, the distribution is not a valid probability distribution.

You can also find the requirement that beta (denoted as b) has to be positive in the scipy documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gausshyper.html).
Changing beta to a positive parameter immediately solves your problem:

```
from scipy import stats
distribution = stats.gausshyper
params = [9.482986347673158, 16.65813644507513, 38.11083665959626, 16.08698932118982, -13.387170754433273, 18.352117022674125]
test_val = [-0.512720,1,1]

arg = params[:-2]
loc = params[-2]
scale = params[-1]

print("cdf:",distribution.cdf(test_val,*arg, loc=loc,scale=scale))
print("pdf:",distribution.pdf(test_val,*arg, loc=loc,scale=scale))
```

Output:

```
cdf: [1. 1. 1.]
pdf: [3.83898392e-32 1.25685346e-35 1.25685346e-35]
```

,where all cdfs integrate to 1 as desired. Also note that your x also has to be between 0 and 1, as described in the scipy documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gausshyper.html).

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, however i'm curious about one detail: i got the parameters from scipy's .fit() so that means the fit() is returning non valid parameters.

Comment: Could you post the code for the fit method? Maybe its returning the parameters in a different order?